# Is $f$ integrable on the Jordan domain $V$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

If $D$ is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$ and $f$ is integrable on $D$, $V$ is a Jordan domain containing in $D$, is $f$ integrable on $V$?

I think it is true. I tried to consider the restriction function of $f$ on V, but I don't know how to discuss. And I think maybe we can use the contradiction.

Comment: Are you aware that a bounded function $f$ is integrable (on a rectangle) iff its set of discontinuities has measure zero?

Comment: Yes, I know this. Also for the boundary of $V$ have Jordan content 0(measure 0). But I don't know whether $f$ if discontinuous on the boundary of $V$.

Comment: If the boundary of $V$ has measure $0$, then do you need to worry about $f$ being discontinuous there? (Although, I think you might need to think about $f\cdot\chi_V$ and not just $f$.)

Comment: Thanks. May be I can think $1$ is not continuous on the boundary $V$, then so is $1\cdot f$.

Comment: That is not true if $f = 0$ identically.

Comment: Oh thanks, so I need to consider the case $f\equiv 0$, then it must be integrable on V.

Comment: I didn't get what you mean. You don't really have to consider cases separately. I shall write an answer now and let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the usual definition of the Riemann integral, to show that $\displaystyle\int_Vf$ exists, you need to show that $\displaystyle\int_Rf\cdot\chi_V$ exists for some closed rectangle $R \supset V$. (The choice of $R$ does not matter.)

---

Let us fix some closed rectangle $R \supset D$. (Note that $D$ is bounded.)

Since $\displaystyle\int_Df$ exists, we see that the set of discontinuities of $f\cdot\chi_D$ is of measure zero.

Now, we show that the same is true for $f\cdot\chi_V$.

Let us consider the three different sets where $x \in R$ can be:

1. $x \in \operatorname{int}V$.
   In this case, $x \in \operatorname{int}D$ as well thus, and in a neighbourhood of $x$, we have that
   $$f = f\cdot\chi_V = f\cdot\chi_D.$$
   Thus, if $f\cdot\chi_V$ is discontinuous at $x$, then so is $f\cdot\chi_D$.
   Since the set of discontinuities of the latter has measure zero, we see that
   $$D_1 := \{x \in \operatorname{int}V \mid f\cdot\chi_V \text{ is discontinuous at }x\}$$
   also has measure zero.
2. If $x \in \operatorname{boundary}V$.
   Since $V$ is a Jordan domain, the set of all such $x$ itself has measure zero. In particular, so does the set
   $$D_2 := \{x \in \operatorname{boundary}V \mid f\cdot\chi_V \text{ is discontinuous at }x\}.$$
3. $x \in R \cap \operatorname{int}(\Bbb R^n\setminus V).$
   $f\cdot x_V$ is continuous at any such $x$ as it is identically $0$ in a neighbourhood of $x$.

---

Thus, we see that the complete set of discontinuities of $f$ is $D_1 \cup D_2$ which has measure zero. Thus, $f$ is integrable on $V$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I  am clear about this now. Actually what I thought is to consider $f\cdot 1_V$. Since we know the set of discontinuities of  $f\cdot 1_D$ has measure 0, also $V$ is a Jordan domain, then the set discontinuities of $1_V$ is the boundary $V$. Hence we can think $f\cdot 1_V$. Your proof is clearer, thanks again!

Comment: Then it looks like I've just organised what you were thinking! (I used $\chi_V$ instead of $1_V$.)